# Background com Perdas

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Estou trabalhando com bootstrap e tenho uma imagem em alta definição que sera usada como background de uma área. O que ocorre é que eu tenho dois problemas:

1º Meu background tem que se adaptar com perdas a diversas resoluções, ele sempre estará centralizado, como o exemplo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No caso, a imagem vermelha corresponde a área total da imagem e a azul, apenas o que estará sendo disponível. 
Como poderia proceder?

1º O outro problema é que a imagem terá um scrolling semelhante as imagens de fundo desse site: http://www.whitepavilion.com.br/homologacao/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1º** Sobre a imagem ficar no centro, de forma simples, você pode utilizar o seguinte código CSS:

O que ele faz é basicamente expandir a imagem a todo o contexto da div em que ela está, ajustando a altura e largura quando necessário, e com o comando 'center center' no background você indica que ela deve ser centralizada, não importa o monitor.

```
html{
  background: url(URL_Exemple.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Exemplo Prático: [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/marceloavf/29gdL4vd/)

---

**2º** Sobre o Scrolling, pelo que entendi está se referindo ao "Parallax", efeito de a imagem se mover lentamente dentro do bloco conforme o usuário faz o movimento no scroll.

Existe varias formas de se realizar esse procedimento, recomendo dar uma lida neste tópico do nosso amigo Diego Eis

[**Parallax simples com JQuery e CSS**](http://tableless.com.br/parallax-simples-com-jquery-e-css/)